# Did UICollectionView change protocol along with Xcode 7, swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

MyCollectionViewController subclasses **UICollectionViewController**, **UICollectionViewDelegate** and **UICollectionViewDataSource**. It worked just fine before I switched to Swift 2.0. Now I get the following error: "Redundant conformance of MyCollectionViewController to protocol UICollectionViewDataSource".

I checked the official UICollectionView Class Reference but it still states that I have to use both the Delegate and the Data Source. If I don't subclass the Delegate and the Data Source it seems that the app works. Is there anything in particular I should note? Or maybe some updated official documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UiCollectionViewController defines itself as conforming to UICollectionViewDelegate and Datasource.

By declaring the conformance again you are making a redundant declaration.

If you read the error message that is exactly what it's telling you.

Just delete the Delegate and Datasource conformance from your subclass.